How to add Kotlin-kapt plugin in android studio JellyFish
Recently I have been trying to do databinding and using dagger hilt. Then I ugraded the IDE to the latest version. Now everything has changed: Dependencies have been added to libs.versions.toml and are used in build.gradle as below:
dependencies {
    implementation libs.androidx.core.ktx
    implementation libs.androidx.appcompat
    implementation libs.material
    implementation libs.androidx.activity
    implementation libs.androidx.constraintlayout
    implementation libs.intuit.sdp
    implementation libs.intuit.ssp
    implementation libs.hilt.android.compiler
    implementation libs.hilt.android
    testImplementation libs.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.androidx.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.androidx.espresso.core
}

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt)
}

[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
jetbrains-kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }
jetbrains-kotlin-kapt = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt", version.ref = "kotlin" }

Old version:
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'
}

Now I am trying to add kapt plugin but cannot figure out how to do it. I get this error message:
Error resolving plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt', version: '1.9.0']
> The request for this plugin could not be satisfied because the plugin is already on the classpath with an unknown version, so compatibility cannot be checked.


With what do you need help? Your code looks good fine. But please don't provide our code as screenshot, provide it as text so we can more easily copy it. Please [edit] your question and replace the screenshots with text and describe in more detail what your problem is.

added build error image

Are you serious? I just asked you to remove the screenshots - and you added new ones instead? We need the question to provide code and error messages as text.

this is presets code in gradle and are defaults while setting up project the images are for reference that where am i facing the problem because programmetically its correct. still shared the code and image both

We do not need redundant information, code as text is all that is needed. I removed all screenshots. Now, please also provide the error message (as text!) and show us where in your gradle files you actually apply the kapt plugin.

please do not post images of text

@MarcinOrlowski its for reference as the issue I am facing.

As I already explained, we need all references as text. Screenshots are neither needed nor wanted, they are just adding noise and distract from the relevant information. I reverted the post to my previous edit, please do not rollback again. Instead, add the missing information (like the error message and how you apply the plugin) as text.

With the recent Android Studio updates, you can now use version catalogs to manage plugin versions, including Kotlin kapt. Here's how to use aliases for plugins in the libs.versions.toml file and in your build.gradle.
Here’s the complete setup:
Step 1: Define Plugins in libs.versions.toml
In the gradle/libs.versions.toml file, define the plugins with aliases, such as Kotlin and kapt:
[versions]
kotlin = "1.8.10"

[plugins]
....
kotlin-kapt = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt", version.ref = "kotlin" }

Step 2: Configure Project-Level build.gradle
In the project-level build.gradle file, declare the plugin aliases but don’t apply them globally:
// Project-level build.gradle
plugins {
    ...
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin-kapt) apply false
}

Step 3: Apply Plugins in the Module-Level build.gradle
In the module-level build.gradle (such as app/build.gradle), you can apply these plugins as needed:
// Module-level build.gradle
plugins {
    ...
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin-kapt)
}


make this changes
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }`enter code here`


Is that text for the kapt.plugin, the TOML file or the Gradle file? What extra code do you need in place of enter code here?

sorry but this doesn't help

plugins {
alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
alias(libs.plugins.gms.google.services)
//    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.kapt)
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt")

}

this is work for me . I ma facing the same issue :- Error resolving plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt', version: '2.0.20-Beta1']

The request for this plugin could not be satisfied because the plugin is already on the classpath with an unknown version, so compatibility cannot be checked.
but adding  id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt") instead of
alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.kapt) work for me

